# I want to create a genric format function, what is default value of top,bottom,right,left

Tags: python, xlsx, xlsxwriter

```
def columnandcellformate(sheet_name,bold = 0,font_color = '#000000',bg_color = '#ffffff',align = '' ,bottom = 0 ,top = 3,right = 0,left = 0,font_size = 10 ,starcolumn = 0, endrow = 0 ):
    global sheet_format
    sheet_format=sheet_name.add_format({
                        'bottom':bottom,
                        'top' : top,
                        'bg_color':bg_color,
                        'font_color' : font_color,
                        'align':align,
                        'font_size':font_size,
                        'bold': bold,
                        'font_name':'Batang'
                       })
```

What is default value of top,bottom,right,left, My function is making cell top,bottom,right and left blank

Comment: give more details about what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your default background color may have been causing some issues with the cell borders.  I've added a few conditions based on whether you want these called by your function or not.  These conditions make use of Format Methods such as `format.set_bg_color()`, `format.set_bottom()` ([see docs for more information on these](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html)).  They only provide a background color if you change it from the default.

```
import xlsxwriter

def columnandcellformate(bold = 0, font_color = '#000000', bg_color = 'none', align = '' , bottom = 999, top = 999, right = 999, left = 999, font_size = 10):
    global sheet_format
    sheet_format=workbook.add_format({
    'font_color' : font_color,
    'align': align,
    'font_size': font_size,
    'bold': bold,
    'font_name': 'Batang'
    })
    if bg_color != 'none':
        sheet_format.set_bg_color(bg_color)
    if bottom != 999:
        sheet_format.set_bottom(bottom)
    if top != 999:
        sheet_format.set_top(top)
    if right != 999:
        sheet_format.set_right(right)
    if left != 999:
        sheet_format.set_left(left)


workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
ws = workbook.add_worksheet('test_1')

columnandcellformate()
ws.write('B1', 'foo', sheet_format)
columnandcellformate(bold = 1, font_color = '#9C0006', bg_color = '#FFC7CE', align = '', bottom = 2, top = 1, right = 1, left = 1, font_size = 10)
ws.write('B3', 'bar', sheet_format)
workbook.close()
```

**Expected Output:**

[image: Expected Output of test.xlsx]

Comment: If is set 999, self._write_border(xf_format)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xlsxwriter/styles.py", line 429, in _write_border
    xf_format.bottom_color)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xlsxwriter/styles.py", line 469, in _write_sub_border
    attributes.append(('style', border_styles[style]))
IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: Yes, `workbook.add_format({})` will not accept 999 as a value. Be sure to copy the function exactly as I have it so that it is only setting values if it is not equal if one of the function parameters is changed to something other than 999.  Perhaps run the script as I've posted to convince yourself that it works.

Comment: Thanks for you help

Answer (score 1):

The default values for format properties are almost all 0/False. See the [initialization code](https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/blob/master/xlsxwriter/format.py#L46) for a format object.